# Can Firebase be used without clients logging in?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a project that might use Firebase *only* for messaging. The goal is for the following to happen:

1. App registers with Firebase on startup
2. App sends Firebase token to our server
3. Our server sends Firebase messages to all clients via the token from step 2

Note there is no step where the user will log into anything or enter any credentials. I am a little confused if this is possible in a production app, as most Firebase documentation talks extensively about different ways to authenticate, either via username/password, OAuth, etc.

The server will be sending different messages to different clients, but that logic will be handled by the server and not by different types of registration to Firebase. I know Firebase supports groups, but to make a long story short it probably won't be leveraged.

Can all this be done on Firebase? Is GCM a better match for these requirements? I feel like we would be throwing away 95% of Firebase and just trying to force it to simplify the messaging part.

Comment: Just for clarity, you just want the database portion of Firebase right? The logic for authentication will be handled by your server?

Comment: You're unlikely to achieve what you want here. Leaving your FCM notifications open ended is an invitation for spam and likely to violate policy in the Apple and Google app stores' terms and conditions.

Comment: Sorry, in the name of shortening my initial post I was not clear. There will certainly be authentication, but it will be handled by our own, existing server/API. The client will need to send any Firebase information to the server directly once the client receives it, and the server will make decisions on which clients to send messages to. We won't be using groups to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Authentication does not at all affect the way that [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) works.  FCM only cares about the token for the app on the device as a means to target the app for messages.  It doesn't care at all if the end user is authenticated by any means.  If you want to associate a token to a user somehow, using Firebase Authentication or some other system, that's up to you.

FCM is an evolution of GCM.  They are powered by essentially the same components.  Using GCM doesn't give you any additional constraints or flexibility than FCM, except for the path to integration in your app.

Comment: So if all we need is the messaging portion, and only intend for the server to poke GCM/FCM to say "send message X to device Y", GCM is probably the best choice? It sounds like Firebase suite will just complicate things.

Comment: You can pick and choose the parts of Firebase that you want to use.  There is no obligation to use any of it that you don't want to use.  But there are some features that work better together, should you choose them.  GCM is being replaced by FCM, so you're better off going with the newer thing.

Comment: Great, this is just what I needed to know. Thanks!